REST API response should return only id or full object?
At work every time I deal with creating CRUD api, I always return the full object for create and update.
Now I'm developing a personal project and I was wondering if it can be a good idea instead to return only id.
This means that if frontend need the full data, will call the exposed API findById.

Not returning this data is totally fine. You should at a minimum return a Location header pointing to the newly created resource with a 201 Created status
Returning a full object can remove one roundtrip. In those cases you should return a Content-Location header. You can also let the client decide if they want it with a Prefer: return=representation header.
General design advice is stop thinking about ids in routes. The entire URL is already unique id.

I'm new to header, do you have any tutorial recommendation to start with to learn more about that ? I have only worked with request body and response body.

@PaulMarcelinBejan I do not. You can probably google something like HTTP headers + [your language/framework of choice]. Good luck!
